# Laravel TokenMismatchException VerifyCsrfToken.php:67 find route

Tags: php, laravel

i have checked the laravel.log of my website and there are a couple of errors, which I want to fix. The most often error is the "TokenMismatchException VerifyCsrfToken.php:67"

Unfortunately I am not able to find out where these errors come from. I have a lot of forms on my website, so i was trying to track the url when the error occurs, but with this code it is not working:

```
\Log::info('TokenMismatch: '.\Route::currentRouteName());
```

Can you help me, how to find out the pages, where these error is appearing ?

Thanks in advice !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `App\Exceptions\Handler` there's a field:

```
protected $dontReport = [
   // etc
   TokenMismatchException::class
   // etc
];
```

If you want the `TokenMismatcheException` to be reported then you need to remove that line.

If you also want to add custom logic to the reporting you can do:

```
public function report(Exception $exception) {
    if ($exception instanceof TokenMismatchException) {
        \Log::info($exeption->getMessage, [ "Current URL: ".url()->current(), $e->getTraceAsString() ]); //Trace is optional but helps
    } else {
         parent::report($exception);
    }
}
```

However the reason the `TokenMismatchException` is not reported by default is that it can cause a lot of noise in the error logs. Crawlers (malicious or not) will constantly trigger such errors as part of their regular work because that's just how they work sometimes.

Comment: thank you @apokryfos. This is an answer. I have just used: url()->current()

Answer (score 1):

I've got the same error message and then figured out that I've missed to add `csrf_token` for the form field.

```
<form action="" class="form-horizontal"  method="post" id="myform" name="distributor_form">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
</form>
```

Comment: is very useful for me thanx a lot

Answer (score 0):

Add this tag to the forms

```
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

Comment: thanks, but you are not helping me. I know what to place, but I do not know how to find out on which page these code is missing.

Comment: Check the URL you are on and search for that path on web.php (route def. file)

Answer (score 0):

Or use `csrf_field()` right after your `form` opening tag like the example below:

```
<form method="POST" action="...">
{{ csrf_field() }}
...
</form>
```